# How to use click function?

Tags: excel, vba, click, submit

Everything works in my code except for the .click at the end.
It disables the button from clicking and it disables the operators ability to press 'enter' with the pasted text.
Only after I click in the text box and enter characters, can I hit enter (or click the button) to search.

```vb
Sub Part_Information()
    '
    ' Part_Information Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a
    '
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim MyURL As String
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Switching to correct page
    'If it can't be found, ends the sub
    'If it is found, then switches to correct search bar and searches for information
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
    For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
        On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
        my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
        my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title

        If my_title = "Parts Intelligence" Then
            Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
            marker = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If marker = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("A matching webpage was NOT found")
    Else
    
        Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
 
        i = 0
        While i < objCollection.Length
            ''''Change name (case sensitive)
            If objCollection(i).class = "simple-search-text form-control short ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" Then
                ' Set text for search
                objCollection(i).Value = ActiveCell.Value
            Else
                ''''Change Type & Name (case sensitive)
                If objCollection(i).class = "btn btn-icon" Then
                    objCollection(i).Click
                    ' "Search" button is found
                End If
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Wend
    
    End If
End Sub
```

This is from the webpage:

Search Button & Search Text Box:
[image: Search Button & Search Text Box]

Comment: So I am confused as to why you are creating a new Internet Explorer object and then turn around trying to find an existing one by it's title. Depending on how many times you've attempted this code, you probably have tens if not a hundred open (and hidden) IE processes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first things first. *Do not **create*** a new IE object if you are trying to find one that already exists. This will eventually start to bog down your computer having a hundred hidden Internet Explorers open in the background.

So, get rid of this

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Switching to correct page
'If it can't be found, ends the sub
'If it is found, then switches to correct search bar and searches for information
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title

    If my_title = "Parts Intelligence" Then
        Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
        marker = 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If marker = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("A matching webpage was NOT found")
Else
```

and instead use something like this function - which will return the IE object that matches a URL and Title.

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim MyURL As String
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set IE = getIE("https://myurl.com", "Parts Intelligence")

If IE Is Nothing Then
    Rem: Add what happens if browser isn't found
End If
```

```
Function GetIE(sLocation As String, sDocTitle As String) As Object

    Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
    Dim sURL As String, sTitle As String
    Dim RetVal As Object

    Set RetVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        sURL = o.document.Location
        sTitle = o.document.Title
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sURL Like "*" sLocation & "*" And sTitle Like sDocTitle & "*" Then
            Set RetVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = RetVal

End Function
```

---

Now, as for your issue. It's difficult to say exactly what is causing this problem without having access to the website in question. However, I had a very similar experience before and what allowed me to get past it was *activating* the textbox by code.

So, for your textbox, try using:

```
yourTextBoxObject.setActive
```

Then filling in the box. This should (hopefully) solve your problem with the button being disabled. With your code, it should look something like:

```
While i < objCollection.Length
        ''''Change name (case sensitive)
        If objCollection(i).class = "simple-search-text form-control short ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" Then
            ' Set text for search
            objCollection(i).setActive
            objCollection(i).Value = ActiveCell.Value
        Else
            ''''Change Type & Name (case sensitive)
            If objCollection(i).class = "btn btn-icon" Then
                objCollection(i).Click
                ' "Search" button is found
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
Wend
```

### Your full code:

```
Sub Part_Information()
    '
    ' Part_Information Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a
    '
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim MyURL As String
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim MyURL As String
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    Set IE = getIE("https://myurl.com", "Parts Intelligence")

    If IE Is Nothing Then
        Rem: Add what happens if browser isn't found
    End If

    Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length
        ''''Change name (case sensitive)
        If objCollection(i).class = "simple-search-text form-control short ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" Then
            ' Set text for search
            objCollection(i).Value = ActiveCell.Value
        Else
            ''''Change Type & Name (case sensitive)
            If objCollection(i).class = "btn btn-icon" Then
                objCollection(i).Click
                ' "Search" button is found
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

```
Function GetIE(sLocation As String, sDocTitle As String) As Object

    Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
    Dim sURL As String, sTitle As String
    Dim RetVal As Object

    Set RetVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        sURL = o.document.Location
        sTitle = o.document.Title
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sURL Like "*" sLocation & "*" And sTitle Like sDocTitle & "*" Then
            Set RetVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = RetVal

End Function
```

Comment: @K.Davis That definitely helped, thank you!

I figured out that the button was "button" and not another "input", which helped me use .Click

My issue now is that once I run the macro once, the button on the page is disabled, or disabled = ""....Is there a way to enable it? If not, I have to click in the text box and hit backspace to have it be enabled again.